# Azure devops split string function to split a string into only 2 strings though there are multiple specified delimiters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm having an issue with a variable in an azure devops pipeline.

Here is my pipeline:

```
parameters:
  - name: testName #3 worded string attached by '-' delimiter
    values:
    - common-name-x
    - new-name-y
    - old-name-y

variables:
  - name: name #This will be the first word in the string example:common
    value: ${{ split(parameters.testName, '-')[0] }}
  - name: changedvalue  #This will be the rest of the string example:name-x
    value: ${{ split(parameters.testName, '-')[1] }}
```

In the variables section, if the string is "common-name-x" Is should be split into "common" and "name-x"
How do I achieve this? I was able to achieve the first one which is "common" but have trouble getting the next string.

Comment: @Olaf Is that Azure Pipelines syntax? Because this question was incorrectly tagged with PowerShell.

Comment: @Olaf - That doesn't work for azure pipeline variables

Answer (score 0):

In this case `split(parameters.testName, '-')` will generate array of 3 items, so you can just concatenate back last two of them to get result you want:

```
parameters:
  - name: testName #3 worded string attached by '-' delimiter
    values:
    - common-name-x
    - new-name-y
    - old-name-y

variables:
  - name: name #This will be the first word in the string example:common
    value: ${{ split(parameters.testName, '-')[0] }}
  - name: changedvalue  #This will be the rest of the string example:name-x
    value: ${{ split(parameters.testName, '-')[1] }}-${{ split(parameters.testName, '-')[2] }}
```